# What is the neural net input/output architecture for generic object detection?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

I am trying to understand this paper: http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Erhan_Scalable_Object_Detection_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf

They worked on object detection *without* classification, which is generalizable even to objects that were not seen in the training set. I am having trying figuring out how one would assign the input/output neurons to train a neural net on this task. For example, let's say you have 100 output nodes, one for each bounding box, and the value indicates the x y location of the box. How do you teach the neural net that order doesn't matter, i.e. reporting the top-left object and then the bottom-right object is just as legitimate as the opposite order? Assume that the training data could come in either order.